# Redirection header works even when content is supposed to be outputed

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers, wamp

The following redirects me to google.com

```
Hello!!!
<?php
echo 'ouch!';
header('Location: http://www.google.com');
?>
```

Shouldn't this not work because text is being outputted before a header is sent?

Comment: Unless this is purely an illustrative example why would you want to echo stuff out, have a redirect in your code and not want it to redirect?

Comment: it is a purely illustrative example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no it will always redirect unless you flush the output before the redirect

```
Hello!!!
<?php
    echo 'ouch!';
    flush(); //This will cause an error on the next line and stop the page from redirecting
    header('Location: http://www.google.com');
?>
```

will not redirect but it will generate an error about headers already being sent